# Visual Studio automatically using the selected Docker Desktop OS Engine

Tags: visual-studio, docker-compose

I have a C# (dotnetcore) project that is written OS agnostic in Visual Studio 2022, with Docker and Docker Compose support. But I also have some other applications on my machine that do require me to use a specific OS in Docker. So sometimes I switch the Docker Desktop OS Engine from Windows to Linux and back. (Containers keep running, even if you switch OS.)

But for this project now that is OS agnostic, I don't want to be bothered with checking and changing the Docker Desktop OS Engine everytime I want to hit F5 to debug it in Visual Studio. So I want Visual Studio to just run in the Docker Desktop Engine OS, or to have Visual Studio automatically change the Docker Desktop Engine OS.

In the C# (dotnetcore) project settings (.csproj), there is a settings `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>` that allows me to choose an OS. I can choose Linux or Windows, and if I remove the setting, it defaults to Linux.

However, this settings is overruled when you run the project via the Docker Compose project.

In the Docker Compose project settings (.dcproj), there is a setting `<DockerTargetOS>` that forces me to choose an OS.

If your Docker Desktop Engine isn't swiched to the same OS as the `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>` setting (Or `<DockerTargetOS>` when using Docker Compose), your application will not run:

```
Your Docker server host is configured for 'Windows', however the docker-compose project targets 'Linux'.
```

If you remove the `<DockerTargetOS>` setting when using Docker Compose, your application will also not run:

```
The "ResolveTargetOS" task was not given a value for the required parameter "TargetOS".
```

Is there a way to make Visual Studio just run the project with respect to the current Docker Desktop Engine setting? Is there maybe some variable I can pass to the .dcproj `<DockerTargetOS>` and the .csproj `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>`? Something like `$(WhatEverDockerDesktopIsSetTo)`? Can I maybe make it use a cmd-line to first get that value and use it? (Such as `docker info | findstr -i ostype`)

Or is there a way to set the OS to a specific value, such as Linux. But then have Visual Studio always automatically change the Docker Desktop Engine to Linux everytime when I hit F5? Is there maybe some Pre-build event in Docker Compose, where I set it to run `"c:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchLinuxEngine` ?